# Java Inheritance using YAML

Tags: java, inheritance, yaml, swagger-codegen, snakeyaml

I want to implement Java inheritance in the generated class files using YAML config. As in I want a particular Custom class to inherit/extend from some other Custom class defined in the same YAML file.

I have tried the following changes:Here the expectation is that the generated UpdateDTO class should inherit from CreationDTO class

```
UpdateDTO:
type: CreationDTO
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
    format: int64
    description: the annotation ID
  category:
    type: string
    description: The annotation or adjustment category
```

Also the second approach that i have tried is as below:

```
UpdateDTO:
type: 
  $ref: '#/definitions/CreationDTO'
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
    format: int64
    description: the annotation ID
  category:
    type: string
    description: The annotation or adjustment category
```

Both the approaches are not working for me. UpdateDTO does not extend CreationDTO

We are using the following maven config to generate the source files:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <id>source</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/daa.yaml</inputSpec>
          <language>xx.xxx.xxx.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaResteasyServerApisCodegen</language>
          <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</output>
          <addCompileSourceRoot>false</addCompileSourceRoot>
          <apiPackage>xx.xxx.xxx.daa.rest</apiPackage>
          <modelPackage>xx.xxx.xxx.daa.rest.model</modelPackage>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>abs-swagger-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Neither the tags of your question nor the text reveal what you are using for generating Java classes from YAML. The Jackson Library you mention does not seem to be relevant. Tell us how you are generating the Java classes.

Comment: My bad. Have edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/358) and [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/810), swagger-codegen does not yet support inheritance for generated Java classes.

Comment: Is there any other plugin which supports inheritance defined in YAML config and creates equivalent Java child and parent classes?

Comment: None that I know of.